# Android Advice - Images

Tags: android

Im new to Android and over the past few days I have been over many tutorials, I was wondering if you could help me with some advice.

I want images on top of each (not completely, there may be some overlapping) other with each image to be clickable.

Whats the best way to do this? Have each image in an image view? Can these be positioned on top of each other? And have onclick listeners?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Imageviews can be stacked by using the framelayout. The framelayout add each child view on top of each other based on the order of the childs ie the last child will be the top most.

Answer (score 0):

Jep, ImageViews are appropriate. Add them to a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and add a onClickListener and you are done.

Have a close look at RelativeLayout's align* attributes.

HTH.